# Mongoose static method populating an array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, where-clause, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

I have a mongoose schema such as:

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    tags : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag' }]
});
```

I am trying to implement a static method which returns the posts having a certain tag. Something like:

```
postSchema.statics.searchByTag = function searchByTag (tag, cb) {
  return this.find().populate('tags')
             .where("tags contains the element tag")
             .exec(cb);
};
```

Questions:

1. Can I use populate in a static method?
2. What is the best way of checking if "tags" contain "tag"?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is then my answer/solution:
1) yes populate works in static methods;
2) This is how I solved the problem, might be not the most efficient way, but it works:

```
postSchema.statics.searchByTag = function searchByTag (tagId, cb) {
    var Posts = [];
    this.find({})
    .populate('author tags')
    .exec(function(err,posts){
    if(err){
        cb(err);
    }else{
        posts.forEach(function(post){
        post.tags.forEach(function(tag){
            if(new String(tag._id).valueOf() == new String(tagId).valueOf()){
            Posts.push(post);
            }
        });         
        });
        cb(null,Posts);
    }
    });
}
```